# Move Next on Multiple Name Iterators

Tags: c#, .net, xpathnodeiterator

I have two XPathNodeIterator nodeI1 and nodeI2.

I have a loop which should go through each
while(nodeI1.MoveNext())

How can I get this loop to automatically start nodeI2.MoveNext() after nodeI1 is done? I don't want to copy paste all the code and make another while loop.

Comment: @user391986: Changing tags to `xpathnodeiterator`. This doesn't relates to XPath expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward way is to put your loop into a method that takes in a node. Then call it twice.

Comment: I agree, you could extract your loop into a seperate method and call it twice.  +1